# Is there a way to escape HTML strings THEN apply html markup in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dom

I have a search form in Angular that receives an object from a database that contains an array of strings. I used pipe that would surround the query with `<mark></mark>` to the result string which would highlight the search query in the result, very handy. So far so good.

I am now trying return and highlight results that are `html-type` strings that contain html markup.
Here comes the difficulty.

Simply displaying the results array will fail, because Angular with automatically sanitize the HTML.

```
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see 
http://g.co/ng/security#xss
```

So I used an Angular safe pipe implementation here to bypass the sanitation:
https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b

```
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
```

At this point the HTML markup will render in the results, which is not good.
So I built an Escape HTML pipe to convert the html into char codes...

```
return value.toString().replace(new RegExp('/</g'), '&lt;').replace(new 
RegExp('/>/g'), '&gt;');
```

Binding to a component.html

```
{{result.value | safe: 'html' | escapehtml | highlight: 
this.search.get('query').value }}
```

Now my escaped html will display in the results, but the highlight pipe will be escaped as well showing `<mark>query</mark>` instead of highlighting the queried text.

Is there any approach in Angular here to get what I'm looking for(escaped HTML strings with html markup), or do I have to give up on my highlight pipe and just show the `escapedHTML` after `sanitization`?

Answer (score 1):

Nearly anything you come up with is going to introduce a security vulnerability that allows xxs injection. The best thing to do is split your string into 3 parts, start, highlight and end and render it with

```
{{start}}<mark>{{highlight}}</mark>{{end}}
```